# Horizontal grouped Barplot with Bokeh using dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, bar-chart, bokeh

[image: My Dataframe]

I have a Dataframe and I want to group by `Type`, and then `Flag` and plot a graph for count of `ID` and another graph grouped by `Type` , `Flag` and  sum of `Total` column in Bokeh.
')

```
 p.hbar(df,
   plot_width=800,
   plot_height=800,
   label='Type',
   values='ID',
   bar_width=0.4,
   group = ' Type', 'Flag'
   legend='top_right')
 [![Expected Graph ][2]][2]
```

If it's not possible with Bokeh what other package can I use to get a good looking graph( Vibrant colours with white background)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the holoviews library, which uses bokeh as a backend.

```
import pandas as pd
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews import opts
hv.extension("bokeh")

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "type": list("ABABCCAD"),
    "flag": list("YYNNNYNY"),
    "id": list("DEFGHIJK"),
    "total": [40, 100, 20, 60, 77, 300, 60, 50]
})

# Duplicate the dataframe
df = pd.concat([df] * 2)
print(df)
  type flag  id  total
0    A    Y   1     40
1    B    Y   2    100
2    A    N   3     20
3    B    N   4     60
4    C    N   5     77
5    C    Y   6    300
6    A    N   7     60
7    D    Y   8     50
```

Now that we have our data, lets work on plotting it:

```
def mainplot_hook(plot, element):
    plot.state.text(
        y="xoffsets", 
        x="total", 
        text="total", 
        source=plot.handles["source"],
        text_align="left",
        y_offset=9,
        x_offset=5
    )
    
def sideplot_hook(plot, element):
    plot.state.text(
        y="xoffsets", 
        x="count", 
        text="count", 
        source=plot.handles["source"],
        text_align="left",
        y_offset=9,
        x_offset=5
    )
    
# Create single bar plot for sum of the total column
total_sum = df.groupby(["type", "flag"])["total"].sum().reset_index()
total_sum_bars = hv.Bars(total_sum, kdims=["type", "flag"], vdims="total")

# Create our multi-dimensional bar plot
all_ids = sorted(df["id"].unique())
counts = df.groupby(["type", "flag"])["id"].value_counts().rename("count").reset_index()
id_counts_hmap = hv.Bars(counts, kdims=["type", "flag", "id"], vdims="count").groupby("type")


main_plot = (total_sum_bars
             .opts(hooks=[mainplot_hook], 
                   title="Total Sum", 
                   invert_axes=True)
)

side_plots = (
        id_counts_hmap
        .redim.values(id=all_ids, flag=["Y", "N"])
        .redim.range(count=(0, 3))
        .opts(
            opts.NdLayout(title="Counts of ID"), 
            opts.Bars(color="#1F77B4", height=250, width=250, invert_axes=True, hooks=[sideplot_hook]))
        .layout("type")
        .cols(2)
)

final_plot = main_plot + side_plots

# Save combined output as html
hv.save(final_plot, "my_plot.html")

# Save just the main_plot as html
hv.save(main_plot, "main_plot.html")
```

[image]
As you can see, the code to make plots in holoviews can be a little tricky but it's definitely a tool I would recommend you pick up. Especially if you deal with high dimensional data regularly, it makes plotting it a breeze once you get the syntax down.

Comment: Thanks . How do I make a horizontal bar? Does hbar work here

Comment: To make a horizontal bar in holoviews, just pass `invert_axes=True` to the call to `opts`. To make the plot on the left horizontal bars do: `total_sum_bars.opts(title="Total Sum", invert_axes=True)` Then to change the bars on the right, you'll need to pass it into `opts.Bars(..., invert_axes=True)`

Comment: Which function should I add the total value of each bar. I  want to show the total value of each bar on the image..

Comment: Also I cant see the plot on the spyder console, is there nay way to save only the final plot separtely as image or pdf.? It shows me only `:HoloMap   [day]
   :Bars   [flag,size]   (count)` in the console

Comment: holoviews doesnt yet properly handle Text with nested bar plots, so you'll need to write your own hook to add it to the underlying bokeh backend. see updated answer. Also you can show your plot by calling bokeh.io.show on the rendered bokeh object as well.

Comment: I tried this it asks me to install selenium and when i did that it asks me for a `geckodriver` ( which is a conda package) I'm a bit afraid doing so at this stage where my project already us will cause corruption of conda packages, Us there any other way to view or save it? I was able to view in browser,/ save in `bokeh` without having to install these...

Comment: When I put `invert_axes = True` in both the `opts` and `opts.Bars` it worked in creating the bars horizontally, but i cannot get the `total` value numbers against each bar. Also I wanted to know if we can only save the main image as png/pdf( Im guessing that requires the `geckodriver`

Comment: You'll need to flip the x/y args inside of the hook to get the text to show up.
In order to save to a png, you will need selenium installed appropriately. However you can export an html file without selenium, I'll update the answer.

Comment: Ya it basically opens in the browser, is there any way to save only the *final plot* out of the 5 *plots* .The labels on image ` A`,`B`, `C`, `D`  is there any way to make it display straight (90 degree rotation)..problem is this looks neat but I have 10 letters in my label including a underscore so that would take up lot of space Also I would like to know what his line of code do..`redim.range(count=(0, 3)`

Comment: Unfrotunately you can not export a png/jpg from bokeh. See https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/export.html - you'll need to install selenium and geckodriver, if you're using anaconda this should be perfectly simple though. To rotate your axis labels, just specify `xrotation=90` and/or `yrotation=90` in your call to `.opts(..., xrotation=90)` I added `redim.range(count=(0, 3))` to change the axis limits to range from 0 to 3 because it was 0 to 1 before and you would not be able to see the value labels without increasing the axis limit range.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Even if I  install this geckodriver, is it possible to only save the final `total plot` as a image and leave out the rest..?

Comment: Oh sorry for not responding to that earlier. I'll update my answer with how you can do that.

Comment: Thanks. I have a question though.. if the `ID` column where to be a string like `ABC34` then in that case what should i change this to `.redim.values(id=all_ids, flag=["Y", "N"])`

Comment: If the name of the column you keep your IDs in is "ABC34" then you'll need to change that to `.redim.valies(ABC34=all_ids, flag=["Y", "N"])`. Also you'll need to swap out "ID" for "ABC34" in the rest of the chunk.

Comment: No I meant each of my id in the `id` column is a string not a number

Comment: Ah, then it should be fine to be left as is. Did something unexpected happen?

Comment: `Total Sum` ,`id` column loooks messy like a concat of srings and `'>=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'` happened. My `id` column has string values and has duplicates, I need to get distinct of it in one graph and count of `ids` grouped by `type` as another

Comment: I added duplicates and string ids into my snippet and it worked fine. Maybe you can open a new question and post a dataframe more related to the current question you have and the error in its entirety? I can't seem to reproduce it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222739/discussion-between-cameron-riddell-and-puzzled).